# simultaneously read and write data into file

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter

i want simultaneously read and write data into file.  Can i use StreamReader and StreamWriter with only file? And why code below doesnt out numbers?

```
var stream = new FileStream(path,FileMode.Create,FileAccess.ReadWrite,FileShare.ReadWrite);
var sw = new StreamWriter(stream);
var sr = new StreamReader(stream);


for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    sw.WriteLine(i);
}

stream.Seek(0,SeekOrigin.Begin);
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
 Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
}

stream.Close();
```

Comment: You should close your stream in a `using` statement.

Comment: Be very careful here. It's one thing to have two open FileStreams on a given file using the operating system's read/write sharing facilities. It's a totally different thing to have a StreamReader and StreamWriter accessing the same FileStream instance. Internal buffering in both StreamReader and StreamWriter could give you unexpected results if you try to interlace the order of your reads and writes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [`Flush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush.aspx) the StreamWriter to force it to actually write the data from its internal buffer to the stream.
Alternatively, you can set the StreamWriter's [`AutoFlush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush.aspx) property to `true`